# Unable to create index using Logstash on Opensearch

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, opensearch

I am trying to take data from a kafka endpoint and create a index of it on Opensearch and I am doing it using a Logstash instance, I am already able to take data from mssql, postgres and a few other sources so the configuration of opensearch being incorrect gets ruled out automatically, Below is one of the redacted conf for kafka that I am passing to the logstash binary. Just to add more information this entire infra is on Kubernetes.

```
input {
  kafka{
    codec => json
    bootstrap_servers => "kafka.development:9092"
    topics => "elastic-test"
  }
}

 

output {
  stdout {  
        codec => json_lines  
    } 
  opensearch{
        hosts => "https://opensearch-cluster-master.logging"
        user => "user"
        password => "pass"
        index => "kafka-top"
        ssl_certificate_verification => false
  }
}
```

**The pipeline does get started though with logs as below**

````
./logstash -f /air-connectors/kafka.conf --path.data /tmp/kafka --debug
    Using bundled JDK: /opt/logstash/jdk
    Sending Logstash logs to /opt/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
    [2023-05-08T13:11:42,964][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Log4j configuration path used is: /opt/logstash/config/log4j2.properties
    [2023-05-08T13:11:42,966][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"8.6.1", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.3.8.0 (2.6.8) 2022-09-13 98d69c9461 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 17.0.5+8 on 17.0.5+8 +indy +jit [x86_64-linux]"}
    [2023-05-08T13:11:42,968][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] JVM bootstrap flags: [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=true, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom, -Dlog4j2.isThreadContextMapInheritable=true, -Djruby.regexp.interruptible=true, -Djdk.io.File.enableADS=true, --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/java.nio.channels=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED]
    [2023-05-08T13:11:42,969][DEBUG][logstash.modules.scaffold] Found module {:module_name=>"fb_apache", :directory=>"/opt/logstash/modules/fb_apache/configuration"}
    [2023-05-08T13:11:42,969][DEBUG][logstash.plugins.registry] Adding plugin to the registry {:name=>"fb_apache", :type=>:modules, :class=>#<LogStash::Modules::Scaffold:0x80d38af @directory="/opt/logstash/modules/fb_apache/configuration", @module_name="fb_apache", @kibana_version_parts=["6", "0", "0"]>}
    [2023-05-08T13:11:42,970][DEBUG][logstash.modules.scaffold] Found module {:module_name=>"netflow", :directory=>"/opt/logstash/modules/netflow/configuration"}
    [2023-05-08T13:11:42,970][DEBUG][logstash.plugins.registry] Adding plugin to the registry {:name=>"netflow", :type=>:modules, :class=>#<LogStash::Modules::Scaffold:0x2c861fc2 @directory="/opt/logstash/modules/netflow/configuration", @module_name="netflow", @kibana_version_parts=["6", "0", "0"]>}
    [2023-05-08T13:11:42,975][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] Setting global FieldReference escape style: none
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,084][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] -------- Logstash Settings (* means modified) ---------
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,085][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] allow_superuser: true
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,085][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] node.name: "air-worker-0"
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,085][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] *path.config: "/air-connectors/kafka.conf"
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,085][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] *path.data: "/tmp/kafka" (default: "/opt/logstash/data")
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,085][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] modules.cli: #<Java::OrgLogstashUtil::ModulesSettingArray: []>
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,086][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] modules: []
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,086][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] modules_list: []
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,086][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] modules_variable_list: []
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,086][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] modules_setup: false
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,086][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] config.test_and_exit: false
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,087][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] config.reload.automatic: false
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,087][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] config.reload.interval: #<Java::OrgLogstashUtil::TimeValue:0x2bbc3119>
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,087][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] config.support_escapes: false
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,087][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] config.field_reference.escape_style: "none"
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,087][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] metric.collect: true
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,087][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.id: "main"
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,087][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.system: false
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,088][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.workers: 16
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,088][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.batch.size: 125
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,088][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.batch.delay: 50
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,088][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.unsafe_shutdown: false
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,088][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.reloadable: true
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,089][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.plugin_classloaders: false
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,089][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.separate_logs: false
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,089][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.ordered: "auto"
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,089][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.ecs_compatibility: "v8"
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,089][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] path.plugins: []
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,089][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] config.debug: false
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,090][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] *log.level: "debug" (default: "info")
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,090][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] version: false
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,090][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] help: false
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,090][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] enable-local-plugin-development: false
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,090][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] log.format: "plain"
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,090][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] api.enabled: true
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,090][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] api.http.host: "127.0.0.1"
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,091][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] api.http.port: 9600..9700
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,091][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] api.environment: "production"
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,091][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] api.auth.type: "none"
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,091][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] api.auth.basic.password_policy.mode: "WARN"
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,091][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] api.auth.basic.password_policy.length.minimum: 8
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,091][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] api.auth.basic.password_policy.include.upper: "REQUIRED"
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,091][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] api.auth.basic.password_policy.include.lower: "REQUIRED"
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,091][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] api.auth.basic.password_policy.include.digit: "REQUIRED"
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,092][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] api.auth.basic.password_policy.include.symbol: "OPTIONAL"
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,092][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] api.ssl.enabled: false
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,092][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] queue.type: "memory"
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,092][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] queue.drain: false
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,092][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] queue.page_capacity: 67108864
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,092][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] queue.max_bytes: 1073741824
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,093][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] queue.max_events: 0
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,098][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] queue.checkpoint.acks: 1024
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,098][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] queue.checkpoint.writes: 1024
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,098][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] queue.checkpoint.interval: 1000
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,098][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] queue.checkpoint.retry: true
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,099][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] dead_letter_queue.enable: false
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,099][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] dead_letter_queue.max_bytes: 1073741824
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,099][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] dead_letter_queue.flush_interval: 5000
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,100][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] dead_letter_queue.storage_policy: "drop_newer"
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,100][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] slowlog.threshold.warn: #<Java::OrgLogstashUtil::TimeValue:0x1c64febb>
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,100][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] slowlog.threshold.info: #<Java::OrgLogstashUtil::TimeValue:0x3d496009>
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,100][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] slowlog.threshold.debug: #<Java::OrgLogstashUtil::TimeValue:0x4ad31999>
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,100][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] slowlog.threshold.trace: #<Java::OrgLogstashUtil::TimeValue:0x28860097>
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,100][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] keystore.classname: "org.logstash.secret.store.backend.JavaKeyStore"
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,100][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] keystore.file: "/opt/logstash/config/logstash.keystore"
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,100][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] *path.queue: "/tmp/kafka/queue" (default: "/opt/logstash/data/queue")
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,100][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] *path.dead_letter_queue: "/tmp/kafka/dead_letter_queue" (default: "/opt/logstash/data/dead_letter_queue")
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,101][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] path.settings: "/opt/logstash/config"
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,101][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] path.logs: "/opt/logstash/logs"
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,101][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] --------------- Logstash Settings -------------------
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,102][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,114][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Initializing API WebServer {"api.http.host"=>"127.0.0.1", "api.http.port"=>9600..9700, "api.ssl.enabled"=>false, "api.auth.type"=>"none", "api.environment"=>"production"}
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,119][DEBUG][logstash.api.service     ] [api-service] start
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,133][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Setting up metric collection
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,137][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.os] Starting {:polling_interval=>5, :polling_timeout=>120}
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,140][DEBUG]    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,216][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Starting agent
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,218][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Starting API WebServer (puma)
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,221][DEBUG][logstash.config.source.local.configpathloader] 
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,221][DEBUG][logstash.config.source.local.configpathloader] Reading config file {:config_file=>"/air-connectors/kafka.conf"}
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,224][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Trying to start API WebServer {:port=>9600, :ssl_enabled=>false}
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,227][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Converging pipelines state {:actions_count=>1}
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,228][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Executing action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main}
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,231][DEBUG][org.logstash.secret.store.SecretStoreFactory] Attempting to exists or secret store with implementation: org.logstash.secret.store.backend.JavaKeyStore
 WebServer {:port=>9607, :ssl_enabled=>false}
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,245][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Trying to start API WebServer {:port=>9608, :ssl_enabled=>false}
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,291][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9608, :ssl_enabled=>false}
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,416][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections] Reflections took 69 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 127 keys and 444 values
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,431][DEBUG][org.logstash.secret.store.SecretStoreFactory] Attempting to exists or secret store with implementation: org.logstash.secret.store.backend.JavaKeyStore
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,450][DEBUG][logstash.plugins.registry] On demand adding plugin to the registry {:name=>"kafka", :type=>"input", :class=>LogStash::Inputs::Kafka}
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,474][DEBUG][logstash.plugins.registry] On demand adding plugin to the registry {:name=>"json", :type=>"codec", :class=>LogStash::Codecs::JSON}
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,489][DEBUG][logstash.codecs.json     ] config LogStash::Codecs::JSON/@id = "json_a664a5c4-7a51-4fcd-b3d1-e13a14eb2e14"
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,490][DEBUG][logstash.codecs.json     ] config LogStash::Codecs::JSON/@enable_metric = true
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,490][DEBUG][logstash.codecs.json     ] config LogStash::Codecs::JSON/@charset = "UTF-8"
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,955][DEBUG][org.logstash.config.ir.CompiledPipeline][main] Compiled output
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,955][DEBUG][org.logstash.config.ir.CompiledPipeline][main] Compiled output
     P[output-stdout{"codec"=>"json_lines"}|[file]/air-connectors/kafka.conf:12:3:```
    stdout {  
            codec => json_lines  
        }
    ```] 
     into 
     org.logstash.config.ir.compiler.ComputeStepSyntaxElement@3fdc2b9c
    [2023-05-08T13:11:43,956][DEBUG][org.logstash.config.ir.CompiledPipeline][main] Compiled output
     P[output-stdout{"codec"=>"json_lines"}|[file]/air-connectors/kafka.conf:12:3:```
    stdout {  
            codec => json_lines  
        }
    ```] 
     into 
     org.logstash.config.ir.compiler.ComputeStepSyntaxElement@3fdc2b9c
    [2023-05-08T13:11:44,032][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline Java execution initialization time {"seconds"=>0.46}
    [2023-05-08T13:11:44,037][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
    [2023-05-08T13:11:44,042][DEBUG][logstash.javapipeline    ] Pipeline started successfully {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x53c6610b@/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:131 run>"}
    [2023-05-08T13:11:44,042][DEBUG][org.logstash.execution.PeriodicFlush][main] Pushing flush onto pipeline.
    [2023-05-08T13:11:44,052][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
    [2023-05-08T13:11:44,073][WARN ][org.apache.kafka.clients.CommonClientConfigs][main][1ba95385298db642543b1ac3599be601d0078bc82c740e4786edf80b67c09300] Configuration 'client.dns.lookup' with value 'default' is deprecated and will be removed in future version. Please use 'use_all_dns_ips' or another non-deprecated value.
    [2023-05-08T13:11:44,074][DEBUG][org.apache.kafka.clients.CommonClientConfigs][main][1ba95385298db642543b1ac3599be601d0078bc82c740e4786edf80b67c09300] Disabling exponential reconnect backoff because reconnect.backoff.ms is set, but reconnect.backoff.max.ms is not.
    [2023-05-08T13:11:44,074][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig][main][1ba95385298db642543b1ac3599be601d0078bc82c740e4786edf80b67c09300] ConsumerConfig 
    [2023-05-08T13:11:44,324][DEBUG][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main]    [2023-05-08T13:11:44,143][INFO ][logstash.codecs.json     ][main][1ba95385298db642543b1ac3599be601d0078bc82c740e4786edf80b67c09300]  DescribeProducers(61): 0 [usable: 0], UNKNOWN(65): 0, UNKNOWN(66): 0, UNKNOWN(67): 0).
    [2023-05-08T13:11:44,325][DEBUG][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main][1ba95385298db642543b1ac3599be601d0078bc82c740e4786edf80b67c09300] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Sending metadata request MetadataRequestData(topics=[MetadataRequestTopic(topicId=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA, name='elastic-test')], allowAutoTopicCreation=true, includeClusterAuthorizedOperations=false, includeTopicAuthorizedOperations=false) to node kafka.development:9092 (id: -1 rack: null)
    [2023-05-08T13:11:44,325][DEBUG][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main][1ba95385298db642543b1ac3599be601d0078bc82c740e4786edf80b67c09300] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Sending METADATA request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=METADATA, apiVersion=11, clientId=logstash-0, correlationId=2) and timeout 40000 to node -1: MetadataRequestData(topics=[MetadataRequestTopic(topicId=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA, name='elastic-test')], allowAutoTopicCreation=true, includeClusterAuthorizedOperations=false, includeTopicAuthorizedOperations=false)
    [2023-05-08T13:11:44,326][DEBUG][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main][1ba95385298db642543b1ac3599be601d0078bc82c740e4786edf80b67c09300] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Sending FIND_COORDINATOR request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=FIND_COORDINATOR, apiVersion=3, clientId=logstash-0, correlationId=0) and timeout 40000 to node -1: FindCoordinatorRequestData(key='logstash', keyType=0)
    [2023-05-08T13:11:44,328][DEBUG][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main][1ba95385298db642543b1ac3599be601d0078bc82c740e4786edf80b67c09300] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Received METADATA response from node -1 for request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=METADATA, apiVersion=11, clientId=logstash-0, correlationId=2): MetadataResponseData(throttleTimeMs=0, brokers=[MetadataResponseBroker(nodeId=0, host='kafka-0.kafka-headless.development.svc.cluster.local', port=9092, rack=null)], clusterId='06BOGbugRJqo0BIZZnWnoQ', controllerId=0, topics=[MetadataResponseTopic(errorCode=0, name='elastic-test', topicId=T2WhcZ9NSjGufv-o0yHWjg, isInternal=false, partitions=[MetadataResponsePartition(errorCode=0, partitionIndex=0, leaderId=0, leaderEpoch=0, replicaNodes=[0], isrNodes=[0], offlineReplicas=[])], topicAuthorizedOperations=-2147483648)], clusterAuthorizedOperations=-2147483648)
    [2023-05-08T13:11:44,332][DEBUG][org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata][main][1ba95385298db642543b1ac3599be601d0078bc82c740e4786edf80b67c09300] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Updating last seen epoch for partition elastic-test-0 from null to epoch 0 from new metadata
    [2023-05-08T13:11:44,333][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata][main][1ba95385298db642543b1ac3599be601d0078bc82c740e4786edf80b67c09300] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Cluster ID: 06BOGbugRJqo0BIZZnWnoQ
    [2023-05-08T13:11:44,333][DEBUG][org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata][main][1ba95385298db642543b1ac3599be601d0078bc82c740e4786edf80b67c09300] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Updated cluster metadata updateVersion 2 to MetadataCache{clusterId='06BOGbugRJqo0BIZZnWnoQ', nodes={0=kafka-0.kafka-headless.development.svc.cluster.local:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)}, partitions=[PartitionMetadata(error=NONE, partition=elastic-test-0, leader=Optional[0], leaderEpoch=Optional[0], replicas=0, isr=0, offlineReplicas=)], controller=kafka-0.kafka-headless.development.svc.cluster.local:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)}
    
    [2023-05-08T13:11:44,338][DEBUG][org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator][main][1ba95385298db642543b1ac3599be601d0078bc82c740e4786edf80b67c09300] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Heartbeat thread started
    [2023-05-08T13:11:44,338][DEBUG][org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator][main][1ba95385298db642543b1ac3599be601d0078bc82c740e4786edf80b67c09300] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Sending synchronous auto-commit of offsets {}
    [2023-05-08T13:11:44,338][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator][main][1ba95385298db642543b1ac3599be601d0078bc82c740e4786edf80b67c09300] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] (Re-)joining group
    [2023-05-08T13:11:44,339][DEBUG][org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator][main][1ba95385298db642543b1ac3599be601d0078bc82c740e4786edf80b67c09300] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Joining group with current subscription: [elastic-test]
    [2023-05-08T13:11:44,361][DEBUG][org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator][main][1ba95385298db642543b1ac3599be601d0078bc82c740e4786edf80b67c09300] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Sending JoinGroup (JoinGroupRequestData(groupId='logstash', sessionTimeoutMs=10000, rebalanceTimeoutMs=300000, memberId='', groupInstanceId=null, protocolType='consumer', protocols=[JoinGroupRequestProtocol(name='range', metadata=[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 12, 101, 108, 97, 115, 116, 105, 99, 45, 116, 101, 115, 116, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0])])) to coordinator kafka-0.kafka-headless.development.svc.cluster.local:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
    [2023-05-08T13:11:44,366][DEBUG][org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector][main][1ba95385298db642543b1ac3599be601d0078bc82c740e4786edf80b67c09300] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Created socket with SO_RCVBUF = 32768, SO_SNDBUF = 131072, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node 2147483647
    [2023-05-08T13:11:44,366][DEBUG][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main][1ba95385298db642543b1ac3599be601d0078bc82c740e4786edf80b67c09300] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Completed connection to node 2147483647. Fetching API versions.
    [2023-05-08T13:11:44,366][DEBUG][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main][1ba95385298db642543b1ac3599be601d0078bc82c740e4786edf80b67c09300] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Initiating API versions fetch from node 2147483647.
    [2023-05-08T13:11:44,367][DEBUG][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main][1ba95385298db642543b1ac3599be601d0078bc82c740e4786edf80b67c09300] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Sending API_VERSIONS request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=API_VERSIONS, apiVersion=3, clientId=logstash-0, 
    2023-05-08T13:12:03,121][DEBUG][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main][1ba95385298db642543b1ac3599be601d0078bc82c740e4786edf80b67c09300] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Sending FETCH request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=FETCH, apiVersion=12, clientId=logstash-0, correlationId=53) and timeout 40000 to node 0: FetchRequestData(clusterId=null, replicaId=-1, maxWaitMs=500, minBytes=1, maxBytes=52428800, isolationLevel=0, sessionId=1580643679, sessionEpoch=35, topics=[], forgottenTopicsData=[], rackId='')
    [2023-05-08T13:12:03,182][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.cgroup.cpuresource] File /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/kubepods.slice/kubepods-besteffort.slice/kubepods-besteffort-pod95684a9f_ebf9_4964_b27e_ed968d84646d.slice/crio-12acc1f3914c72c67a01078418fc5d202e9ec14fc827d3bb801b23c57853b048.scope/cpu.cfs_period_us cannot be found, try providing an override 'ls.cgroup.cpu.path.override' in the Logstash JAVA_OPTS environment variable
    [2023-05-08T13:12:03,182][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.cgroup.cpuresource] File /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/kubepods.slice/kubepods-besteffort.slice/kubepods-besteffort-pod95684a9f_ebf9_4964_b27e_ed968d84646d.slice/crio-12acc1f3914c72c67a01078418fc5d202e9ec14fc827d3bb801b23c57853b048.scope/cpu.cfs_quota_us cannot be found, try providing an override 'ls.cgroup.cpu.path.override' in the Logstash JAVA_OPTS environment variable
    [2023-05-08T13:12:03,182][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.cgroup.cpuresource] File /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/kubepods.slice/kubepods-besteffort.slice/kubepods-besteffort-pod95684a9f_ebf9_4964_b27e_ed968d84646d.slice/crio-12acc1f3914c72c67a01078418fc5d202e9ec14fc827d3bb801b23c57853b048.scope/cpu.stat cannot be found, try providing an override 'ls.cgroup.cpu.path.override' in the Logstash JAVA_OPTS environment variable
    [2023-05-08T13:12:03,182][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.cgroup.cpuacctresource] File /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct/kubepods.slice/kubepods-besteffort.slice/kubepods-besteffort-pod95684a9f_ebf9_4964_b27e_ed968d84646d.slice/crio-12acc1f3914c72c67a01078418fc5d202e9ec14fc827d3bb801b23c57853b048.scope/cpuacct.usage cannot be found, try providing an override 'ls.cgroup.cpuacct.path.override' in the Logstash JAVA_OPTS environment variable
    [2023-05-08T13:12:03,220][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"G1 Young Generation"}
    [2023-05-08T13:12:03,221][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"G1 Old Generation"}
    [2023-05-08T13:12:03,534][DEBUG][org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator][main][1ba95385298db642543b1ac3599be601d0078bc82c740e4786edf80b67c09300] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Sending Heartbeat request with generation 92 and member id logstash-0-5fa3eaed-7fb1-4e34-a039-679367e4c36b to coordinator kafka-0.kafka-headless.development.svc.cluster.local:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
    [2023-05-08T13:12:03,534][DEBUG][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main][1ba95385298db642543b1ac3599be601d0078bc82c740e4786edf80b67c09300] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Sending HEARTBEAT request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=HEARTBEAT, apiVersion=4, clientId=logstash-0, correlationId=54) and timeout 40000 to node 2147483647: HeartbeatRequestData(groupId='logstash', generationId=92, memberId='logstash-0-5fa3eaed-7fb1-4e34-a039-679367e4c36b', groupInstanceId=null)
    [2023-05-08T13:12:03,535][DEBUG][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main][1ba95385298db642543b1ac3599be601d0078bc82c740e4786edf80b67c09300] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Received HEARTBEAT response from node 2147483647 for request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=HEARTBEAT, apiVersion=4, clientId=logstash-0, correlationId=54): HeartbeatResponseData(throttleTimeMs=0, errorCode=0)
    [2023-05-08T13:12:03,535][DEBUG][org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator][main][1ba95385298db642543b1ac3599be601d0078bc82c740e4786edf80b67c09300] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Received successful Heartbeat response
    [2023-05-08T13:12:03,622][DEBUG][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main][1ba95385298db642543b1ac3599be601d0078bc82c740e4786edf80b67c09300] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Received FETCH response from node 0 for request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=FETCH, apiVersion=12, clientId=logstash-0, correlationId=53): FetchResponseData(throttleTimeMs=0, errorCode=0, sessionId=1580643679, responses=[])
    [2023-05-08T13:12:03,622][DEBUG][org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler][main][1ba95385298db642543b1ac3599be601d0078bc82c740e4786edf80b67c09300] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Node 0 sent an incremental fetch response with throttleTimeMs = 0 for session 1580643679 with 0 response partition(s), 1 implied partition(s)
    [2023-05-08T13:12:03,623][DEBUG][org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher][main][1ba95385298db642543b1ac3599be601d0078bc82c740e4786edf80b67c09300] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Added READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch request for partition elastic-test-0 at position FetchPosition{offset=4, offsetEpoch=Optional[0], currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[kafka-0.kafka-headless.development.svc.cluster.local:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)], epoch=0}} to node kafka-0.kafka-headless.development.svc.cluster.local:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)
    [2023-05-08T13:12:03,623][DEBUG][org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler][main][1ba95385298db642543b1ac3599be601d0078bc82c740e4786edf80b67c09300] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Built incremental fetch (sessionId=1580643679, epoch=36) for node 0. Added 0 partition(s), altered 0 partition(s), removed 0 partition(s) out of 1 partition(s)
    
    

 
    And this literally goes on for an infinite number of times, Has anyone seen this type of issue before? Please let me know if there is something I am doing wrong, I have already tried removing opensearch from output and just keeping stdout part, but as I have read it only outputs what its getting from kafa on screen, Any help is appreciated. 
    Thanks in advance
````